# Simplifying a regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm trying to solve a problem that requires me to simplify regular expressions.

Here is the starting point:
$(aaa)^*b(bbb)^*$

Which I rewrote as follows:
$(a^3)^*b(b^3)^*$

However I've been trying to simplify it without success. Is there a way it could be simplified any further?

Comment: How do you measure that an expression is simpler than another one?

Comment: My terminology is probably flawed, maybe "reducing" would be better? For example, $aaa(aaa)*$ can be "reduced" to $(aaa)^+$ .

Answer (score 1):

You might of course also write your regular expression as $(a^3)^*(b^3)^*b$, but I don't think you can find a shorter regular expression for your language.